# Get multiple codes, concatenate them by '|' delimited, from one id

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

First 2 columns is what gets put into the datatable. I'm trying to create a Linq query to get what's to the right of it

[image]

What I tried:

```
var test = (from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
               group row by row.Field<string>(0) into grp
               select new
               {
                    StudentID = grp.Key,
                    Code = grp.Select(r => r.ItemArray[1].ToString() + "|")
               }).ToList();
```

Returns:

```
{ StudentID = "431708", Code = {System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator<System.Data.DataRow, string>} }
```

if you drill down in debug. I see the values I need.

Comment: Call `ToList` on your inner `select new`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use string.Join

```
var test = (from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
               group row by row.Field<string>(0) into grp
               select new
               {
                    StudentID = grp.Key,
                    Code = string.Join("|", grp.Select(r => r.ItemArray[1].ToString()).ToArray())
               }).ToList();
```

Comment: Nice. Thanks @bhmahler